# Split html canvas with video in 3 sections

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to show a very wide video (12000px) on a web page in 3 different sections of 4000px width, like in this image

[image: Video]

I know that this can be done with canvas, but really I can't get it to work.

I already saw some examples but I didn't found this case in particular. Thanks in advance for any help.

-- edit --

The ideal solution would be having an animation like in this pen
http://www.codepen.io/sephhh/pen/OVpELO?editors=1010

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" height=200 width=200 style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

---

```
// set up initial variables
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,0);
ctx.lineTo(100,200);
ctx.stroke();

function drawCircle(x){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,100,10,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle="red";
  ctx.fill();
}
var x = 0;
setInterval(function(){ 
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
  drawCircle(x%200);
  x++;
}, 25);
```

to have the same effect of starting in the 1st section an continue to the others using something like in this example where the canvas is spread in rectangles: http://craftymind.com/factory/html5video/CanvasVideo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually not that hard to do.

First you have to create three canvas elements, eachs height equal the height of the video and the width is a third of the video's width.

Inside a loop triggered by e.g. **setInterval** you can draw specific parts of the source video to each canvas using the **drawImage()** method.

The drawImage method accepts several parameters - we need 9 of them.
context.drawImage(source, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, targetX, targetY, targetWidth, targetHeight);

source: the video

sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth and sourceHeight: These define a rectangular area of the source we want to draw on the canvas. So for the first canvas this would be the left third of the video.

targetX, targetY: these determine the coordinates we want to draw the image at - always 0,0

targetWidth: will always be a third of the video
targetHeight: equal to the video's height

Here's an example:

```js
var canvas;
var theVideo = document.getElementById("video");
var segment = theVideo.width / 3;
for (var a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas" + a)
  canvas.width = segment;
  canvas.height = document.getElementById("video").height;
}

function draw() {
  for (var a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
    document.getElementById("canvas" + a).getContext("2d").drawImage(theVideo, a * segment, 0, segment, theVideo.height, 0, 0, document.getElementById("canvas" + a).width, document.getElementById("canvas" + 0).height);
  }
}
var interval = setInterval(draw, 20);
```

```css
section {
  float: left;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<video id="video" width="320" height="176" loop preload autoplay muted style="display:none">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

<section>
  <canvas id="canvas0"></canvas>
</section>
<section>
  <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
</section>
<section>
  <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</section>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! What about having an animation like this one https://codepen.io/sephhh/pen/OVpELO?editors=1010 to have the same effect of starting in the 1st section an continue to the others? Can we use something like in this example where the canvas is spread in rectangles? http://www.craftymind.com/blowing-up-html5-video-and-mapping-it-into-3d-space/